# How can I get all dates in a query if there is not data in that dates?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Currently, I have a ORACLE query that gives me the following data:

[image]

As you can see, there is not data between the 11th and the 12th, and I would need to get this result if there is not data:

[image]

I currently have this query:

```
select
    TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd') AS FECHA,
    PEDIDO,
    COUNT(TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd')) AS CANTIDAD
FROM PEDIDOS_TIENDA
GROUP BY TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd'), PEDIDO
ORDER BY TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd') ASC
```

I'm a little lost, can you help me?

Comment: Those questions can't solve my problem because I can't create a table with the dates...

Comment: @shubham Those are MySQL solutions and not Oracle solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```sql
SELECT c.fecha,
       t.pedido,
       COALESCE(t.cantidad, 0) AS cantidad
FROM   (
         SELECT min_fecha + LEVEL - 1 AS fecha
         FROM   (
           SELECT MIN(TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd')) AS min_fecha,
                  MAX(TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd')) AS max_fecha
           FROM   PEDIDOS_TIENDA
         )
         CONNECT BY LEVEL - 1 <= max_fecha - min_fecha
       ) c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (
         SELECT TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd') AS FECHA,
                PEDIDO,
                COUNT(TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd')) AS CANTIDAD
         FROM   PEDIDOS_TIENDA
         GROUP BY TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd'), PEDIDO
         ORDER BY TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd') ASC
       ) t
       ON c.fecha = t.fecha
ORDER BY fecha, pedido
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PEDIDOS_TIENDA ( fecha_pedido, pedido ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-12-09', 'Aleron' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-09', 'Aleron' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-10', 'Bugia' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-10', 'Focos' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-10', 'Ruedas' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-10', 'Focos' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-11', 'Llantas' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-13', 'Llantas' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FECHA | PEDIDO | CANTIDAD |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 09-DEC-20 | Aleron | 2 |
> | 10-DEC-20 | Bugia | 1 |
> | 10-DEC-20 | Focos | 2 |
> | 10-DEC-20 | Ruedas | 1 |
> | 11-DEC-20 | Llantas | 1 |
> | 12-DEC-20 |  | 0 |
> | 13-DEC-20 | Llantas | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b94b180d65056839fbb7bb5572cbe345)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query . using table t2, calculate the dates between the smallest date and the largest date, and then right outer join it to the main table.

```
SELECT t2.dt AS fecha,t1.pedido,COALESCE(t1.cantidad,0)
FROM mytable t1 

RIGHT OUTER JOIN

(SELECT (SELECT MIN(fecha) FROM mytable) + level - 1 dt
FROM  DUAL CONNECT BY level <= ((SELECT MAX(fecha) FROM mytable) - (SELECT MIN(fecha) FROM mytable) + 1)) t2

ON t1.fecha = t2.dt
ORDER BY t2.dt
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e7bdf7c2d5204d49b1af31fb6924907e)